# parallel game play in three scenes

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2d and im developing my first iphone game. The requirement of the game is to run it on 3 views simultaneously, but user can see only one view at a time and other two views are hidden but active. user will have to switch between views to play game. which technique should i use to make it possible as game should not stop at any view, while switching.

Any suggestion and help will be worthy of bundle of thanx.

Comment: I wouldn't update or draw hidden views! At least, not frequently..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2d is made to run only 1 scene at the time. So cross that one.

I think the easiest approach is to run each view on a layer and simply change the z-Order of the layer to switch. You might have some problems with that, as there are no standard ways for doing this, but that is the challenge of programming a game.

Also, I would recommend being careful with these kind of things for your first game. You will have to think about turning touch input on and off and be very mindful of memory management, running multiple layers. 
If I were you, I'd try something really basic first or redeveloping the idea so that it is not necessary to have these views active at the same time. Often some math can take you a long way, but to help you with that, you should provide more information.

Comment: thanx a lot for your detailed answer. actually it is requirement of my client. im experienced with business apps but this time he pushed me to  the hell of cocos2d. Other than this feature game is simple and im almost gone through it.
now im thinking either to convince the client or to go for some painful coding. Thanx again Job...

Comment: Hy Job... is it possible to create a scrollView of width 3x of iphone screen width and then use them as three scenes and make parallel gameplay? with swipe user can move to next and previous. am i thinking right ?

Comment: I'm having my doubt, but I honestly don't know that much about scrollView. The usage of resources would be the same if all were active. 
I would say that the way you will implement multiple scenes is irrelevant, though layers would be the easiest. The real problem is having multiple views running. Depending on what you're actually running, try to reformulate and go into details for a new question.

I did find a link that might interest you:
[link](http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/21/cocos2d-and-uiscrollview/)